Is their a way to pass an iteration index as a permanent integer in python?
I am trying to iterate through a range, creating a new tkinter button widget for each number in the range, resulting in a keypad formation. Each button needs to send a different integer to a list when pressed, but passing i to it causes it to references i's final value (after iterating through the button creations), causing every single button to return an 8.
I need every button to return the index that was there when creating the button.
    for i in range(9):
        gem_button = Button(key_pad, image= images[i], command= lambda: add_gem(i, player_moves, moves.selected), width= 32, height= 32)
        gem_button.grid(row= 4 + (i % 3), column= i // 3)

I have tried passing a list index instead, but this does not change the result at all.
button_range = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
...
gem_button = Button(key_pad, image= images[i], command= lambda: **add_gem(button_range[i]**, player_moves,

This confuses me, because in the same line of code, I am passing i as an index to the button's image, and the images display the correct image index.

The difference is that images[i] is evaluated at the time the Button is created, but the lambda is evaluated when the Button is clicked (which is long after the loop has reached its final iteration).
